# overriding placeholder font css in all browsers

Tags: css, placeholder, pseudo-element

I am trying to override the font of all headers, input, select, text area and input placeholders on my site with the following code:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
button, input, select, textarea,
:-ms-input-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family:some font name;
}
```

The problem is, for some reason it isn't working on Chrome. If I delete the `:-moz` and `:-ms` references, then chrome works fine, which leads me to believe that Chrome doesn't like pseudo-classes for some reason? I'm stumped, because I can't see why pseudo-classes that have nothing to do with Chrome would make it not work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make separate declarations for it to work in all browsers, otherwise a conflict will cause undesired results like this.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: somefont;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: somefont;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: somefont;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: somefont;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: somefont;
}
```

Comment: The reason to this is that an unrecognized selector makes the entire statement malformed, thus skipped due to CSS error processing rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors