# Internet Explorer placeholder styling issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Trying to apply style to placeholder I faced a problem, that in IE (all versions) placeholder text color doesn't apply. It only takes the color of text input

```
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: white; 
}

input {
    color:black;
}
```

after applying this code the color of a placeholder will be black.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In my css I specified for the form inputs (div_name form > input {}) color of the text which was more valuable parameter for browser than specified as selector:-ms-input-placeholder {} placeholder color. (Which is quite strange. They are for different purposes, but ok)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify this rule to specific input:

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: white; 
}

input {
    color:black;
}
```

From [Internet Explorer Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **selector**:-ms-input-placeholder {...}

Please note that this will work only on IE>10 browsers.

Comment: Are you sure compatibility mode is not enabled and your browsers works not in Quirks mode? Do you have doctype on your page?

Comment: Yes - i'm sure. Doctype is also in my html

Comment: Do you have some page example? Does this link works for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ct0Lx3t3/ . Also if you use 3rd party plugins to add placeholders for not supported browsers can you disable them and look if they caused the issue?

Comment: Deleted all js additions and left css - doens't work. In jsFiddle it is working okay. Strangely, with my css for input elements.

Comment: @eatmypants That's odd, seems like problem in another place. Do you have an live example?

Comment: Unfortunately can't show it due to privacy reasons. Will try to find the solution by myself. Definitely will post it here if find one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for support for all browsers take a look at this answer:

[How to support placeholder attribute in IE8 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-attribute-in-ie8-and-9)

Comment: OP looking for styling placeholder, not for enabling it in older browsers. Also link only answers should be comments instead http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Already using it, but after I added it - the color of the IE < 10 placeholder is the same as in IE10.

Comment: Or Marked as duplicates

Answer (score 0):

IE11 requires the `!important` flag to override the default user agent styles.

Here is a ruleset that works for IE versions 10 and 11.

```
/* - Internet Explorer 10–11
   - Internet Explorer Mobile 10-11 */
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: white !important;
}
```

See answer to question [Placeholder CSS not being applied in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827689/1071200) for details about all browsers.

For IE versions older than 10, you need a polyfill to even support placeholders. CSS will be different for these. Refer to a polyfill.