# IE 11 doesn't render placeholder color properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, placeholder, html-rendering

In Bootstrap 3.2.2 there is declaration:

```
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

IE 11.0.17 (possibly other versions as well) doesn't render it correctly, the placeholder remains black.

Answer (score 7):

I put the following in my custom CSS and it fixed the problem:

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199047/placeholder-css-not-being-applied-in-ie-11 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer 11 needs the `!important` flag to override the default user agent styles.

```
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999 !important;
}
```

This is not an issue in Microsoft Edge which uses `::-ms-input-placeholder` and no `!important` flag. Internet Explorer 10 does not need the `!important` flag.