# Not getting Placeholder in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs6

on load of my grid I am setting some default value in widget column which is `tagfield` type. For loading that I am using `placeholder` but placeholder is not working in IE11. Can any body give some soluion. I also tried this kind of answer in my solution but not working.

[Placeholder CSS not being applied in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199047/placeholder-css-not-being-applied-in-ie-11/26164266#26164266)
My code is :

```
var SValue = Obj.getAttribute('Val');
    if(field.xtype == "tagfield"){
        field.setValue(SValue);
        field.inputEl.set({'placeholder':SValue});
    }else{
        field.setValue(SValue);
    }
```

This is working fine in chrome but not in IE11

Comment: I would have thought `field.inputEl.setAttribute('placeholder,SValue);` I guess .set is extjs?- can you hit `<>` and create a [mcve]?

Comment: @mplungjan SValue  is not an object. It is some value which is getting from Obj.getAttribute('Val');.

Comment: Right. Please create a [mcve] - it is impossible to help if we cannot console.log(SValue)

Comment: ok sure, I am trying to create fidller

Comment: As you can see I can set the placeholder using plain JS: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7r1aqm81/