# How to set a color for placeholders?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set a color for placeholders in the inputs, if you ask, why? it's becasue I have a theme customization where you are able to change font color and background colors, so, that color should be applied to the entire system, but not to the placeholders, and that's applied there.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: gray !important;
}
```

It works fine for Chrome & Firefox, but I have an issue with IE, it doesn't work there, it displays the theme color. E.g, theme is configured with red color, with that CSS, IE should show the placeholders with gray color, but it's shown as red.

Comment: What version of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check for existing questions on the community before posting your question. That way we can get rid of duplicate questions.

[Placeholder CSS not being applied in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199047/placeholder-css-not-being-applied-in-ie-11)