# Placeholder font style is coming as different for textfield and textarea

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a textfield and a textarea and both of them have a placeholder. But the font style of the placeholder is different as compared to the textfield and textarea. Please show me how to keep the same font style.

```
<form> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="just for testing the style">
    <textarea placeholder="just for testing the style"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: why different you can check your code from css stylesheet

Comment: The placeholder has some default styles according to browser's default css settings, so you have to define your own, if u to want change it http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531799/overriding-placeholder-font-css-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set them to the same font family in the CSS:

```
textarea,
input[type=text] {
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention font family for textarea like **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/E4FCG/)**

**css**

```
textarea{font-family:arial;}
```